# Can Xerces Java Parser load Resource from ClassPath and run it with Jar executable?

Tags: java, xsd, xerces, domparser

I want to validate xml file against xs schema file. Now, I'm providing xml file as a command line arg. and need to keep my schema file inside my classpath.

For this I've used Xerces (2_11_0) parser for java

I've kept schema file inside package and added this folder inside my classpath.

```
String SCHEMA = this.getClass().getResource(SCHEMA_NAME).getFile();
parser.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation", SCHEMA);
```

When I run the code inside eclipse, it works like charm but the problem arises when I export my project as an executable jar.

I try running the jar and it is not able to find SCHEMA file.

> file:/C:/**MY_JAR!**/PACKAGE/SCHEMA_FILE.xsd

Can anyone let me know the reason why this is not working from executable jar and the solution for it?

Let me know if more info is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because the URL for `this.getClass().getResource(SCHEMA_NAME)` is now something like `jar:file:/C:/MY_JAR!/PACKAGE/SCHEMA_FILE.xsd`. See if just using `this.getClass().getResource(SCHEMA_NAME).toString()` will work.

Comment: It is not working after converting to string too. I'm running "java -jar my_jar.jar" and it gives same error file:/C:/MY_JAR!/PACKAGE/SCHEMA_FILE.xsd

Comment: please edit your original question and add the stacktrace. please also add some output for the value of `SCHEMA`.